# Javascript - Finding length of line segments from an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, line

I'm working on a project that requires me to parse an array of an array of values, and work out the length of the line segments.

The array that I have is in the form where each element is a tuple of `(xCoordinate, yCoordinate)`:

```
[[1.4,2.8],[2.3,2.2],[3.2,1.6],[3.8,1.1]]
```

I would like to calculate the length of the line segment between, say, array element 1 `(1.4,2.8)` and 2 `(2.3,2.2)`, then 2 and 3, 3 and 4, etc. Also I want to avoid for-loops if possible, to try to enhance my knowledge of functional programming, coming from a Java background.

I am aware that I probably have to parse in both values into a map function, and perform a calculation like `sqrt((y2-y1)^2+(x2-x1)^2))`

I have an `xyDistance()` function written:

```
function xyDistance(from,to){
    var xy=from.split(",");
    var x1=xy[0];
    var y1=xy[1];
     
    var xy=to.split(",");
    var x2=xy[0];
    var y2=xy[1];
    var dt = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2);
    return dt;
}
```

Which seems to work fine, when I manually enter the co-ordinates.
Then I imagine I want something like

```
var map = arr.map(arr[x] => xyDistance(arr[x],arr[x+1]))
```

But this throws errors.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#slice` to remove the last element and then use `Array#map` along with `Math.hypot` to find the distance between adjacent line segments.

```js
const arr = [[1.4,2.8],[2.3,2.2],[3.2,1.6],[3.8,1.1]];
const res = arr.slice(0, -1)
   .map(([x, y], idx)=>Math.hypot(x - arr[idx + 1][0], y - arr[idx + 1][1]));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: It seems like my array does not have square brackets around the individual coordinates, rather: ['1.4,2.8','2.3,2.2','3.2,1.6','3.8,1.1'] etc. I'm rather confused how I would edit the syntax of map([x,y],idx), because intuitively I would want to write map('x,y',idx) but I feel as though a string is not what I want there.

Comment: @Lawrence123 You can first convert the array to correct format: `arr = arr.map(x => x.split(',').map(Number));`

Comment: Hmm, This is really interesting @iota. Are you able to clarify how the .map(Number)); suddenly seems to generate square brackets from somewhere?

Comment: @Lawrence123 `.map(Number)` just converts each element from a string to a number. `.split(',')` is what converts the string into a two element array.

Comment: @Lawrence123 Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your expression has syntax error:

```
var map = arr.map(arr[x] => xyDistance(arr[x],arr[x+1]))
```

Should be corrected as:

```
var map = arr.map((element, x) => xyDistance(arr[x], arr[x+1]))
```

Noted that when you have `n` elements, you only get `n - 1` distance. That’s why iota’s answer slice off the last element before calling `Array#map`.

```
var map = arr.slice(0, -1).map((element, x) => xyDistance(arr[x], arr[x + 1]))
```

Second part of your problem is that `xyDistance` function needs some fix. Apparently the elements in your array are strings, not tuple. You’ve given misleading example code in your post. So in order to parse those string elements into tuple of numbers, you need to cast string type to number type:

```js
function xyDistance(from,to){
    var xy=from.split(",");
    // trim any excessive whitespaces, then convert to number type:
    var x1=Number(xy[0].trim());
    var y1=Number(xy[1].trim());
     
    var xy=to.split(",");
    var x2=Number(xy[0].trim());
    var y2=Number(xy[1].trim());
    var dt = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2);
    return dt;
}
```

And you’re good to go now.